# C# Should I manually remove the event handler I declared?

Tags: c#, event-handling

Okay, make an example here:

1. I have UserControl A, UserControl B, UserControl C and one Windows Form.
2. This Windows Form is only started with UserControl A.
3. UserControl C has [Next] and [Back] buttons.
4. Say, UserControl A is declared with an event handler. One of function in UserControl A will actually raise the event call to execute one function at UserControl C.
5. So, at UserControl C, I have to add with

> "UserControlA.OneFunction += this.UserControlC_Function;"

1. If I click Next button at UserControl C, it will dispose the UserControl A and add new UserControl B to the Windows Form. But I never remove this event handler manually.

One of the function in UserControl A is the caller (where event is declared).
One of the function in UserControl C is the listener.

So, these are my questions:

- Should I manually remove the handler before UserControl A disposed?
- Will this User Control A dispose automatically remove the handler that declared previously?
- Should I add this somewhere?

> "UserControlA.OneFunction -= this.UserControlC_Function;"

Comment: Could you please expand the second line Say, I manually added an event handler to my Windows Form to fire a function call at UserControl A a little bit further? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: which is the event source and which is the listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. By convention, we don't. And since no event *should* be invoked after disposal, there is no need to do so unless the control in question is behaving weirdly.
2. No. At least there isn't such code as seen from reflector.

Comment: What if I always press Next and Back Buttons.

Comment: say: UserControl C has [Next] and [Back] buttons to control the UserControl A and UserControl B like a setup wizard. Everytime [Next] button is pressed, this "ctlContent.ctlRBContent1_GetBuildName += this.GetBuildName;" will be executed. But this event is never remove. What will it be?

Comment: However it's a good idea to remove the handler before loosing a reference to C. In this particular case that shouldn't really be a concern but it's a good habit to always do it

Comment: @Rune, do you mean I can do it to the destructor?

Comment: @lannyboy: Once a control is disposed it can never be used again _properly_. Its message loop is terminated and its WndProc will be unregistered. Thus, as long as you dispose of the control properly, it should behave normally.

Comment: @lannyboy: And, an event is actually a wrapper around a delegate (for late-bound method invocation) object stored in the instance of a class. A delegate for an event (a MulticastDelegate) maintains an internal list (array) of delegates, each pointing to an event handler. Thus, the worst result of a not removed event handler on a disposed and **properly written** Control is a memory leak (only if the program is poorly written). So unless you are writing a huge program you don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to remove the handlers in this case because neither the form nor its buttons are referenced by code external to the form, and the entire object graph will therefore be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this post does a really good job explaining when you need to manually remove an event handler and when it is not necessary.

[Do I need to remove event subscriptions from objects before they are orphaned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076401/do-i-need-to-remove-event-subscriptions-from-objects-before-they-are-orphaned/1076469)

Comment: Yes, I meant "when you need to manually remove...". I made the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is released (assuming no other objects has a reference to the objects in question) there's little risk of not removing the event handler, however it's a good idea always to remove the event handler before the object listening can no longer be reach (ie all variables referencing the object i sout of scope) not doing so can create a memory leak.

This is not the case in your situation (if I get what you are describing, code would make it more clear)
The problem would be if you attach a delegate referencing object C to an event on object A and then looses access to C (e.g. assigning a new value to the variable). C would then hang around until A is garbage collected

Answer (score 0):

If the memory lifetime of an event publisher is not limited relative to the useful lifetime of an event subscriber, failure to unsubscribe an event will likely cause a memory leak.  Were it not for the unfortunate hassle of doing so, there wouldn't be any reason for an event subscriber that was being disposed not to unsubscribe from all events, and for an event publisher that was being disposed not to nullify all event subscriptions.  Since neither C# nor VB provides any convenient means of doing those things, however, one has to balance the hassle of proper subscription handling with the fact that in many situations one can get away skimping on it.

Comment: Yea, I get your meaning now. So we have to remove event handler manually before the control is disposed.

Comment: @lannyboy: *IF* the form and control are going to be abandoned at the same time, then abandoning the subscription will not *create* a memory leak; if e.g. a control holds a subscription to e.g. a change-notification event from a long-lived object, leaving the form subscribed to an event from the control could cause what might otherwise be a "small" memory leak to be a bigger one (since the control would keep the form alive, and the form might keep other controls alive, etc.).  As to whether a memory leak which uses 100 bytes a pop is better or worse than one which uses a meg a pop...

Comment: ...there are differing schools of thought on that.  If there are going to be a fixed number of create-abandon cycles (say, 100), it would be better if they use a total of 10,000 bytes than if they use 100,000,000.  On the other hand, if a program does a create/abandon cycle once per minute, it will be obvious within a day that something's wrong if each such cycle ties up a meg.  If each such cycle only takes 100 bytes, one could run the program for a week while using only a meg of extra storage, but processing the subscriptions would get slower and slower until it choked the system.